# flask _app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__ error due to __ident_func__ deprecated in werkzeug 2.1

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I was using `_app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__` for sqlalchemy scoped_session for accessing sqlalchemy models inside flask, without using flask sqlalchemy.

`scoped_session(session_local, scopefunc=_app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__)`

But currently after werkzeug 2.1 `__ident_func__` is  removed and there is no documentation link how to get ident.
[image]

Comment: Looking in Werkzeug v2.0.3 `__ident_func__()`  returns `_get_ident`, The Deprecation warning under `_get_indet()` says to use `greenlet.getcurrent` or `threading.get_ident` for previous behavior.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by removing the .__ident_func__ ```scoped_session(session_local, scopefunc=_app_ctx_stack)```

Comment: I ran into this yesterday with a new test app, just doing `DB = SQLAchemy(APP)`. Forcing `werkzeug` to v2.0.3 made it work

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Dumping relevant requirements.txt would be useful as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do use `scopefunc=greenlet.getcurrent` instead (just `import greenlet` first).

(I tested this with Werkzeug==2.2.2 )

reference:
https://github.com/osohq/oso/pull/1559/files